# Can't login in admin page after accessing my website pages

Tags: python, django

I created a superuser in my admin section. After that I can log in admin page. But Whenever I try accessing some myapp pages then and then I again want to access the admin page It shows this error"Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." I tried it multiple times. And I can create a new superuser by same name I created last time. 
Here is two screenshot:
 
[Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJdtX.png)
[creating superuser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPlmN.png)

How to solve this issue?

Update:

forms.py

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from django import forms
    from .models import Profile

    class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        password= forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username','email','password')

    class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = ('full_name','codeforces_id','Uva_Id')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    codeforces_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    Uva_Id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UserForm,ProfileForm

class UserFormView(View):
    user_form_class = UserForm
    profile_form_class= ProfileForm
    #display a blank form
    def get(self , request):
         user_form = self.user_form_class(None)
         profile_form = self.profile_form_class(None)
         return render(request, 'website/registration_form.html',{
            'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form
            })
    #process form data
    def post(self, request):
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user= user_form.save(commit=  False)
            password= user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            user.set_password(password)

            user.save()
            profile_form.save()

            # auto login 
            user = authenticate(username =username, password = password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('website:index')
        return render(request, 'website/registration_form.html',{
            'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form
            })
```

Comment: please share some codes about User Model and User Model Manager

Comment: Post updated. Actually I'm facing a lot others issue. Tried to debug but now this errors occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating things. So try like this:

```
# forms


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
    full_name = forms.CharField()
    codeforces_id = forms.CharField()
    Uva_Id = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password', 'full_name', 'codeforces_id', 'Uva_Id') 


    def save(self, commit=True):
        full_name = self.cleaned_data.pop('full_name')
        codeforces_id = self.cleaned_data.pop('codeforces_id')
        uva_Id = self.cleaned_data.pop('Uva_Id')
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        Profile.objects.create(
            user=user,
            full_name = full_name,
            codeforces_id = codeforces_id,
            Uva_Id = uva_id
        )
        authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        return user

# view

class UserFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'some_template.html'


# template

<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

# Also you can remove the signal related codes from Profile Model as well
```

Comment: What should I do in post and get method in views.py file ?

Comment: @AhsanShuvo you don't need to override them. Create View will take care of `get` and `post` automatically. and the codes which you had put on there now in Form's `save` method (like authentication).

Comment: My bad. I followed your approach. But now I am facing a new error "ImproperlyConfigured at /website/register/"  "TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'".

Comment: I've fixed the issue. :)

Comment: Ah. I should have named 'template_name', not 'template'. If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) for your views this will authenticate the request.

`settings.py`

```
# Redirect to home URL after login
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Redirect to the login page after log out.
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

`views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.forms import all_valid


#  Using a generic form view and you won't need all of the code above.
class UserFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = UserForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_form'] = context['form']
        context['profile_form'] = self._get_profile_form()

        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def _get_profile_form(self):
        form_kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs['instance'] = request.user.profile()

        return ProfileForm(**form_kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        profile_form = self._get_profile_form()

        if all_valid([form, profile_form]):
            return self.form_valid(form, profile_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, profile_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, profile_form=None):
        # Handle both forms being valid.
        ...

    def form_invalid(form, profile_form=None):
        # Handle one or all of the forms being invalid.
        ...
```